# Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform@55272cc4

Tags: java-8, maven-3, eclipse-oxygen

Error Message:
"
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Carm'.
Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform@55272cc4, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
"

Java1.8

Eclipse Oxygen

Maven3.5.0

What's wrong with this issue? I tried to change to jkd1.6 or jdk1.7. But it seems not jdk problem. And I tried to add certificate to jre/lib/security. Still not work. I found a similar problem on net. [Exlipse Oxygen Maven Problems](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/387096/exclipse-oxygen-maven-problems/) After reading this post, I'm not sure where this problem come from. Eclipse?Maven?or JDK?

Please have a look.

Comment: @csharpnewbie Nope,I guess that's certification problem. Maybe some issue effect the certificate. I have no time nto find the exactly problem. After reinstall the whole system, it works. But it's not the best solution of course.